# Uniform convergence for $\frac{x^2+nx+1}{x+n}$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$

Tags: uniform-convergence

I have this problem: Prove that $ f_n:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $$f_n(x)=\frac{x^2+nx+1}{x+n}$$ converges uniformly to $f(x)=x$. I did this: $$|f_n(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon$$$$ \left|\frac{x^2+nx+1}{x+n} -x \right| <\epsilon$$ 
$$\left|\frac{1}{x+n} \right| \le \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon, n> \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$ What I have to do now?

Comment: You just have to conclude.

Comment: Nothing! You have finished the proof.

Comment: So I don't have to do that messy definition? ( for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $n_{\epsilon}$ so that for every $n>n_{\epsilon}$ to exists $|f_n(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon $ ) I am lost when I see $n_{\epsilon} $

Comment: You showed that $\sup_{x\geq 0}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq 1/n$. Hence, $\sup_{x\geq 0}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, which means by definition that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $[0,+\infty)$.